# in django in my porfolio detail the picture of portfolios are similar

Tags: python, django

in my django project in the index page in portfolio part everything is ok and the picture of each portfolio is correct but when i open a portfolio detail the picture of all portfolio in detail is a similar picture for example my firsts portfolio picture is pic3.jpg and my seconds portfolio image is pic4.jpg in the index page i havent any problem but when i open detail the first and second portfolio image is similar both of them is pic3.jpg

it is my template:

```
            {% for item in porto %}
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app">
              <div  class="portfolio-wrap">
                <a style="display: inline-block; max-width: 360px; max-height: 200px; overflow: hidden;" href="{{ item.image.url }}" data-gallery="portfolio-gallery-app" class="glightbox">
                  <img src="{{ item.image.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="portfolio-info">
                  <h4><a href="{% url 'root:portfolio' id=item.id  %}" title="More Details">{{ item.title }}</a></h4>
                  <p>{{ item.content|truncatewords:3 }}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div><!-- End Portfolio Item -->
            {% endfor %}
```

it is urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

app_name = 'root'

urlpatterns = [
    path("",home,name="home"),
    path("portfolio/<int:id>",port_folio,name="portfolio"),
    path('category/<int:category_id>',home,name='portfilter'),

]
```

it is views:

```
def port_folio(request,id):
    cat = Category.objects.all()
    portos = PortFolio.objects.get(id=id)
    porto = PortFolio.objects.filter(status = True)

    context = {
        'cat':cat,
        'portos':portos,
        'porto':porto,
    }
    return render(request,'root/portfolio-details.html',context=context)
```

and it is my modules.py:

```
class PortFolio(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='port',default='default.jpg')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ouner_name = models.CharField(max_length = 60,default = 'ouner')
    content = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    ouner_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='port',default='default.jpg')
    ouner_category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='portfolio_owner_category')
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='portfolio_category')
    client = models.TextField()
    project_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    project_url = models.URLField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=250,default='bigan')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

it is detail:

```
<div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
      {% for item in porto %}

      <div class="position-relative h-100">
        <div class="slides-1 portfolio-details-slider swiper">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper align-items-center">

            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img src={{item.image.url}} alt="">
            </div>



          </div>
          <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

      </div>

      <div class="row justify-content-between gy-4 mt-4">

        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <div class="portfolio-description">
            <h2>{{item.subject}}</h2>
            <p>
              {{item.content}}
            </p>
            <p>
              {{item.content}}
            </p>

            <div class="testimonial-item">
              <p>
                <i class="bi bi-quote quote-icon-left"></i>
                {{item.description}}
                <i class="bi bi-quote quote-icon-right"></i>
              </p>
              <div>
                <img src={{item.ouner_image.url}} class="testimonial-img" alt="">
                <h3>{{item.ouner_name}}</h3>
                <h4>{{item.ouner_category}}</h4>
              </div>
            </div>

            <p>
              Impedit ipsum quae et aliquid doloribus et voluptatem quasi. Perspiciatis occaecati earum et magnam animi. Quibusdam non qui ea vitae suscipit vitae sunt. Repudiandae incidunt cumque minus deserunt assumenda tempore. Delectus voluptas necessitatibus est.
            </p>
            <p>
              Sunt voluptatum sapiente facilis quo odio aut ipsum repellat debitis. Molestiae et autem libero. Explicabo et quod necessitatibus similique quis dolor eum. Numquam eaque praesentium rem et qui nesciunt.
            </p>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <div class="portfolio-info">
            <h3>Project information</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><strong>Category</strong> <span>{{item.category}}</span></li>
              <li><strong>Client</strong> <span>{{item.client}}</span></li>
              <li><strong>Project date</strong> <span>{{item.project_date}}</span></li>
              <li><strong>Project URL</strong> <a href={{item.project_url}}>view blog</a></li>
              <li><a href={{item.project_url}} class="btn-visit align-self-start">Visit Website</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
      </div>
```